# php number_format display the decimal

Tags: php, codeigniter, numbers

I have a number like this `18914439.4524345860`
and I want to display that number like this `18.91`

I have try the number_format function

```
$x = 18914439.4524345860;
echo number_format($x, 2, ".", ".");
```

and the result is

```
18.914.439.45
```

how to show the number like this `18.91`?

Thanks for your attention...

Comment: [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) with `number_format`?

Comment: first two decimal always?

Comment: But it isn't `18.91` .... Divide by `1000000` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hope this help you :**

```
$int = 18914439.4524345860/1000000;
echo round($int,2);
/* Output 18.91*/
```

Comment: Thank u broo, this one is worked. I really forgot to use that very simple operator (devide). Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1):

`18914439.4524345860` is a complete different number than `18.91`, not just another representation.

You could divide by `1000000` first, and then use `number_format`:

```
$x = 18914439.4524345860;
echo number_format($x / 1000000, 2, ".", ".");
```

Comment: Good spot, regarding the questioners logical error, live example for your provided solution: https://repl.it/repls/MatureFeistySystemsanalysis